# Automatically create pages in phpfox

Tags: phpfox

I have an array of information of places and I wanna use them to create multiple pages in a ***phpfox*** site.

First I tried to manually insert data in phpfox database (in tables of **phpfox_pages** and **phpfox_pages_text**).

The page is shown up in the site but when opening it's link, the site says:

> The page you are looking for cannot be found.

Do you know what other tables should I manipulate to make it work?
Or do you know any plugin for phpfox to do the same?

Thanks,

---

---

**Solved ( With @Purefan Guide):**

> "Pages" also has a user

If you take a look at *`phpfox_user`* table, you'll found out how to fetch new records on that. But there are two ambiguous fields in that table ( *`password`* & *`password_salt`*). You can use this script to create values for the fields:

```
<?php
function generateRandomString()
{
    $length = 164;
    $characters = '-_0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$sSalt = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    $sSalt .= chr(rand(33, 91));
}

$sPossible = generateRandomString();
$sPassword = '';
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) 
{
    $sPassword .= substr($sPossible, mt_rand(0, strlen($sPossible)-1), 1);
    $i++;
}

$password_Salt_Field = $sSalt;
$password_Field = md5(md5($sPassword) . md5($sSalt));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phpfox has 2 very similar modules: "Pages" and "Page", you create "Pages" if you want people to "like" them, post in them, add photos... a "Page" is static so I think this is what you want, in that case I would add to `phpfox_page` and `phpfox_page_text`

Edit: Ok then you are probably forgetting to insert into `phpfox_user`, a "Pages" also has a user, the following should shed some light:

```
$iUserId = $this->database()->insert(Phpfox::getT('user'), array(
            'profile_page_id' => $iId,
            'user_group_id' => NORMAL_USER_ID,
            'view_id' => '7',
            'full_name' => $this->preParse()->clean($aVals['title']),
            'joined' => PHPFOX_TIME,
            'password' => Phpfox::getLib('hash')->setHash($sPassword, $sSalt),
            'password_salt' => $sSalt
        )
    );
```

Look in the file /module/pages/include/service/process.class.add around line 338 (depending on your version).

Comment: Thanks Purefan for response... But what I want is the "Pages" module! To have the like ability and etc.

Comment: Thanks Buddy! You really saved my day (maybe week! :D)!

Comment: Purefan, can you please also help me on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657912/

Thanks beforehand...