# Automatically assign profile pics to pages in phpfox

Tags: phpfox

Followed by my last question: [*Automatically create pages in phpfox*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628637/)

Now I'm trying to assign a list of pre-uploaded images to some pages as their profile picture in phpfox.

After checking data changes in the database, I only realized changes in these two fields:

> *`image_path`* in table of *`phpfox_pages`* (which take a an address to the image file)
>
> *`user_image`* in table of *`phpfox_user`* (which take a string of "user_id+%s".file_extension)

But by inserting data in these two fields in records for a page that has a default profile pic, it's profile pic would not change.

Is there any other fields  or options that I should change?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file /module/pages/include/service/process.class.php In there look for the function update and around line 442 find this

```
if ($this->_bHasImage)
```

This piece of code handles setting an image for the page, notice how it creates three thumbnails, maybe the problem you're having is that you didn't create all the needed thumbs. You also need to update the column `image_server_id`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Purefan...
I already created images thumbs, so I think I couldn't be the problem...
And the `image_server_id` field in my table has a zero value for all of the rows (even pages which have a profile picture)!

Answer (score 0):

look `phpfox_photo` table in that you will find `is_profile_photo` attribute that is always 1 for the profile picture